# SSL with host header not working

Tags: iis, ssl

We have Silverlight application hosted in IIS 8.5 and we tried to configure it with SSL. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It has a valid certificate and the certificate was issued to the conrresponding domain name with host header (ie. https://mysite.mydomain.com ). It does work if we configure it without hostheader (ie. https:// localhost ). Also, we disabled the **loopback** in REGISTRY and also added domainname in REGISTRY at **"BackConnectionHostNames"** with multiline string value "https://mysite.mydomain.com".

What are missing piece of configuration we missed?
Please help.

Comment: Are you testing https locally on the server or from a workstation ?

Comment: Hi - this was already fixed. The problem is that, there is no equivalent URL entry in the active directory DNS so, it can't ping the https URL's. This was the problem of the infra where we hosted our VM's.